# Finding current through a specific resistor

Tags: ohms-law

I am relatively new to circuits. I am struggling to find the current through the resistor here, R1. All I understand is Ohm's law and parallel and series resistors, but I don't know how to apply it here.

[image]

Comment: The top resistor can also be expressed as 2x of the bottom one. And you can also redraw it with the resistors in parallel next to  each other. Maybe that will make it easier to grasp.

Comment: Twice the current flows thru the lower resistor.

Comment: Use the *current divider*

Answer (score 3):

1. Calculate the total resistance (parallel)
2. Calculate the voltage
3. Calculate the current in each resistor

Answer (score 1):

As a variation to what *hacktastical* has suggested, think of equal-value resistors in a circuit that is equivalent to OP circuit...current must be the same in each resistor, if their values are all the same, and add up to 1 A:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS4ETP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Exactly. That's the right way to solve it without even pencil and paper, and the right way to understand the results.

Comment: I wanted to lead that horse to water, so to speak.